# Classify this Large Cardinal

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

If $\kappa$ is a strongly inaccessible cardinal, then let $\Gamma(\kappa)$ be the number of strongly inaccessible cardinals below $\kappa$. If we call $\lambda$ the smallest fixed point of $\Gamma$, then where does $\lambda$ lie on the large cardinal hierarchy?

Comment: Quite low, your condition is much weaker than existence of a 1-inaccessible cardinal.

Comment: If we describe the 'small inaccessible hierarchy' as the collection of cardinals that can be described simply in terms of inaccessible cardinals; i.e. 1-inaccessibles, 2-inaccessibles, hyper-inaccessibles, hyperhyper-inacessibles, etc... then what is the name (i.e. classification) of the smallest large cardinal larger than everything in this collection?

Comment: There isn't necessarily a 'smallest', but generally Mahlo cardinals would be considered to be 'next in line' at least among the prominent cardinals; see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_large_cardinal_properties

Comment: You want the least inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ that has exactly $\kappa$ inaccessible cardinals below it?